# MySQL Queries Insertion order of columns in SubQueries

Tags: mysql

Here column order of first Table is different from second table.

```
insert into storagejobsforreport
select *
from storagejobs
where CustomerId = 2;
```

How it will be inserted in each columns correctly as no. of columns in tables.i don't want to write all column's name sequentially.

Comment: You have to write all column names. And actually, you should generally do it even if (you think that) the columns are in the same order.

Answer (score 1):

you have to do like this

```
insert into storagejobsforreport (col1, col2,..)
select col1, col2...
from storagejobs
where CustomerId = 2;
```